# Linked list traversal in Kernel

Tags: linux, module, linux-kernel, linked-list, kernel

I was using `list_for_each_entry(datastructureptr , &mylinkedlist, head)` to traverse a linked list i created. The output I got was last inserted item is printed first. Is it the expected output. Is there any macro/function to print it in the other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list_for_each_entry` traverses a list from the first to the last item.

You must ensure that the items are inserted in the correct order and at the correct position.
`list_add` inserts at the start of the list; `list_add_tail` at the end.

Comment: I gave the second argument of `list_add` as the list head so got the output like that. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct private {
        char data[30];
    struct list_head head;
    }; 
.......
.....
static struct private mylinkedlist;
....
struct private *datastructureptr=&mylinkedlist;
...
   list_for_each_entry(datastructureptr , &mylinkedlist, head)
       printk( " %s->\n",datastructureptr->data);
```

prints items in fifo way